# Why is this shell output cannot be written to a file?

Tags: linux, echo, stdout, stderr

I'm working on a linux pinephone script that would launch a touchpad emulator. In order to do so, I need to compare the output string of:

```
./TouchpadEmulator /dev/input/event2 /dev/input/event1
```

once I hit enter the terminal shows

```
max x:719 max y:1439
```

and the terminal remains open, without showing any command prompt, which means that the code keeps running in background.

My problem is that I'm trying to output this "max x:719 max y:1430" to some variable, some file, or as an argument for a next command.

I've tried something like

```
./TouchpadEmulator /dev/input/event2 /dev/input/event1 > textfile.txt
```

but the textfile.txt remains empty.

I've also tried

```
echo $(./TouchpadEmulator /dev/input/event2 /dev/input/event1)
```

but the terminal screen remains blank.

My guess is that since the command keeps running in background, the echo never executes, since it waits until the "./TouchpadEmulator ... " is completely executed.

Comment: Probably it's writing to STDERR, not STDOUT.  Redirect just STDERR with `2> textfile.txt`. Read  `man bash`.

Comment: It looks like it never flushes the output buffer - try `stdbuf -oL ./TouchpadEmulator /dev/input/event2 /dev/input/event1 > textfile.txt` to force line-buffered output

Comment: @waltinator This should be the general answer.

Comment: @steeldriver WTF. Keeps on happening. It's in coreutils and i never heard/used it. Upvote for mentioning it.

Comment: Is your issue about finding the size of the screen? This could probably be found in other ways, possibly using `xrandr`.  Minor unrelated comment: The command is running in the _foreground_, not in the background.

Comment: Thanx! This one worked: stdbuf -oL ./TouchpadEmulator /dev/input/event2 /dev/input/event1 > Textfile.txt

Comment: In general, instead of editing the question or the title to indicate the problem being solved, it's better to mark the answer solving it as accepted. Ticking the "accept" checkmark tells the system the case is closed better than a note in the title, it e.g. makes the question show up with different coloring in lists. (In principle, people are supposed to write answers as answers instead of comments...) It's also possible to write an answer yourself if you find the solution via another route, but there's some mandatory delay before you can check a self-answer as accepted.

Comment: anyway, this is a duplicate, there's a number of solutions to this under other questions

Answer (score -1):

Probably it's writing to STDERR, rather than STDOUT.

Redirect STDERR only with `2> textfile.txt`.

Read `man bash`.

Comment: It's more likely that it's actually writing to standard output, but that since the process isn't done and since it's not flushing the output explicitly, the output does not appear.  The standard error stream is never buffered in the same way.